# Database SQL with Elasticsearch / Logstash / Kibana

Tags: mysql, database, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I wish to access SQL database to receive data in ElasticSearch.

Is it possible to connect it directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most direct way I can think is by using the [jdbc-river](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc) plugin.

The basic idea is that you poll a database using the equivalent jdbc driver that dumps your 'select queries' into an elasticsearch index.

Configuration varies depending on your scenario(new/existing index, poll cron) but plugin's [README.md](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/blob/master/README.md) has everything you need to get started!